# Class based Views not recognizing PUT and DELETE methods

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am using class based views and calling PUT , delete methods via ajax but Django is not recognizing these methods and giving 403 error. But according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.http_method_names) it should support these methods

My code:

```
class MynDetail(TokenRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
             ''my code here''  

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ''my code here''

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ''my code here''
```

Django fails to recognize put and delete in above view

**Edit :**

I am using two mixins here;

```
class TokenRequiredMixin(object):
    """
    check if user token cookie exist or not
    """
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'user_token' not in request.COOKIES.keys():
            return redirect(reverse('login-view'))
        else:
            url = get_base_url(request, 'v1')
            valid_token = check_token_validity(url, request.COOKIES.get('user_token'))
            if valid_token.get('token') is None:
                response = redirect(reverse('login-view'))
                response.delete_cookie('user_token')
                response.delete_cookie('user_uid')
                return response
        return super(TokenRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class OrgValidateMixin(object):
    """
    check if user have created an organisation or not
    If not, then redirect him to create org page
    if yes, then he must not able to create another organisation
    so he can't access create organisation page.
    """

    def get_token(self):
        return self.request.COOKIES.get('user_token')


    def get_organisation(self):
        token = self.get_token()
        url = get_base_url(self.request, 'v1')
        return check_user_org(url, token)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_org_exists = self.get_organisation()
        current_path = request.get_full_path()
        create_org_path = reverse('create-org-view')

        if (current_path != create_org_path) and not user_org_exists :


Edit : 

 return redirect(reverse('create-org-view'))
    elif (current_path == create_org_path) and user_org_exists :
        return redirect(reverse('portal-dashboard'))

    return super(OrgValidateMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: HTTP-403 means that access is forbidden. Is there some access mechanism running in `TokenRequiredMixin`?

Comment: Agree to @AKS, "method is not allowed" should be 405, not 403.

Comment: @AKS yes it checks for the token

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `TokenRequiredMixin` and also your ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the CSRF token, same as you would with POST.

I also had the same problem, made a DELETE request and got 403 and checked in the chrome console and got this:

[image]